# OR and AND operation in C

Tags: c, logical-operators

I have a doubt in the program below.

```
int main()
{
    int i = -3,j = 2, k = 0,m;
    m = ++i || ++j && ++k;
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", i, j, k, m);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the output as `-2 2 0 1`.

In OR operation if 1st value is true then it won't evaluate the 2nd one so `i = -2` and `j =2`.
Then comes the AND operation . It will check for both the value to be true.So if `k = 1` then `m = 1`.
So the output should be `-2 2 1 1`. I run and check and got output as `-2 2 0 1` but I could not understand how.

Comment: @Mikola&Michael:Thanks for making me to understand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You used a short circuit or.  Since ++i evaluates to -2, which is not 0, it short circuits and doesn't evaluate the rest of the expression.  As a result, neither j or k get incremented.

Also note that the short circuit operators, || and &&, are left associative and that || is higher precedence than &&.  As a result, the || gets evaluated first, and early outs if the left hand side evaluates to true, while && early outs if the left hand side evaluates to false.

EDIT: Fixed a mistake with explaining the precedence.

Comment: I'm staring at the code and am failing to see why `m = 1` instead of `-2`, which is the result of `++i`.

Comment: I don't think `1` is guaranteed, only non-zero. `m` gets assigned the "boolean" result of the binary operation.

Comment: @Ben Alpert: No, || is *boolean* or (unlike |).  It converts its arguments into a boolean type (ie a 0/1 int) and returns them.  If you give it any non-zero integer for one of its operands, it will return 1.  If it did otherwise, stuff would mess up (for example, think about what would happen if you did this with AND?  Say one value was 2 and the other was 4, you would get 0!)

Comment: Ah, I was getting my languages mixed up and was thinking that it would return the first argument. FWIW, `2 && 4` in JavaScript gives `4`.

Comment: @Ben Alpert: Honest mistake, though one really must wonder why javascript chose that behavior over the older (and perhaps better considered) C semantics?  Anyway, I don't want to start a fight so I should perhaps keep these snarky remarks to myself.  :)

Comment: It's actually often useful; Ruby does the same thing. `x = x || 17` will set `x` to `17` if `x` is undefined (also if it's false).

Comment: It's irrelevant what associativity logical OR and logical AND both have because they don't have the same precedence. Logical AND has a higher precedence than logical OR._That_ is why ++k is not evaluated.

Comment: @Charles Bailey:  Ack!  You are right, have a +1.  I will update the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing after the `||` is evaluated, since the result of the expression `++i` is nonzero.